In REMIX app , Inject Css function error in the chunk generated while building , which leads to application crashing
`Please can anyone help me to find the root cause of the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstChild')" in the Inject CSS function.
Root.tsx
import { type LinksFunction } from '@remix-run/node'
import .........
export const links: LinksFunction = () => [
  { rel: 'preconnect', href: 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/', crossOrigin: 'anonymous' },
  { rel: 'stylesheet', href: stylesheet },
  { rel: 'stylesheet', href: globalstyle },
  { rel: 'stylesheet', href: Navstyle },
  { rel: 'stylesheet', href: Sidebarstyle },
]
export function scrollToSection(section: string) {
  const targetElement = document.getElementById(section)
  if (targetElement) {
    const scrollableParent = targetElement.closest('scrollable-element')
    if (scrollableParent) {
      // Declare scrollPosition here, within the if block
      const scrollPosition = targetElement.offsetTop - 94
      scrollableParent.scrollTo({
        top: scrollPosition,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      })
    } else {
      // Declare scrollPosition here, within the else block
      const scrollPosition = targetElement.offsetTop - 94
      window.scrollTo({
        top: scrollPosition,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      })
    }
  } else {
    console.error(Element with ID '${section}' not found.)
  }
}
export default function App() {
  const config = useLoaderData<typeof loader>()
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <ClarityScript />
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="description" content="Crafting Customer-Driven Digital Experiences" />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>

      <body className="lg:overscroll-y-none overscroll-y-auto">
        <Nav />
        <LoadingTest />
        <Outlet context={config.ENV} />
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
        <Footer />
        <ScrollToTopIcon />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

screebshot of error
I tried by keeping the network to slow 3g, no throttling, fast 3g , just to confirm whether its a network issue but it is not.
So expecting someone could tell me the root cause.
this error occurs randomly , sometimes the application works fine, some times crashes`
